# SQL - Different WHERE clause dependant upon variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a variable to get my SELECT to run in 2 different "modes":

```
DECLARE @Mode as Varchar(1) = 'A'

SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN @Mode = 'A' 
          THEN FieldABC * 2   
       ELSE FieldABC * 3   
    END AS FieldABC,
    CASE 
       WHEN @Mode = 'A' 
          THEN FieldDEF   
       ELSE FieldGHI   
    END AS FieldJKL

WHERE 
    FieldABC BETWEEN 0 AND 100
```

When I want to run the "B" version of the SELECT, I just have to change the variable value. This all works fine.

I now want to change the `WHERE` clause so it too is dependent upon the variable:

```
IF @Mode = 'A' THEN 
   WHERE FieldABC > 0 
ELSE 
   WHERE FieldABC < 0
END IF
```

Except, this syntax is totally nonsense in SQL!

How can I achieve the 2 different flavours of my `WHERE` clause dependent upon the same variable - or some other simple way of switching the `SELECT` between the 2 different modes?

Comment: Try to use [IF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms182717(v=sql.110).aspx) for the variable IF you can. This method can harm your execution plan (in more complex and recurrent queries of course but this is just for the future).

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with a combination of `AND` and `OR` :

```
WHERE (@Mode='A' AND FieldABC > 0)
OR (@Mode='B' AND FieldABC < 0);
```

Or with a `CASE` expression:

```
WHERE CASE 
         WHEN @Mode = 'A' AND FieldABC > 0 THEN 1
         WHEN @Mode = 'B' AND FieldABC < 0 THEN 1
         ELSE 0 
      END = 1;
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much. I had no idea I could use a CASE statement in a WHERE clause, I will investigate further!

Comment: I recommend the case suggestion. Makes more sense for my little brain to follow.

Comment: @SandPiper I actually did it using the And/Or version and it works perfectly. This is the sort of construction that does come easily to me - but for some reason I didn't understand it was possible to use it until I saw Lamak's answer. I don't fully understand the way the CASE works in this context if I'm honest; are we saying that 1=true and 0=false and the result of the CASE statement will actually be a true/false decision?

Comment: No, what it is saying is `IF (CASE STATEMENT) = 1 THEN ...`. In this case, the case statement will evaluate to 1 if the conditions are met and 0 if they aren't. So it simplifies down to is `if I flagged this record with the numeral 1 then select it`.